# How can i get the first hero to be selected as an initial condition in angular2?

Tags: css, angular

In angular2 heros tutorial

```
template: `
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<h2>My Heroes</h2>
<ul class="heroes">
  <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
    [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero"
    (click)="onSelect(hero)">
    <div *ngIf="hero ==heroes[0]"> first hero </div>
    <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
<hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></hero-detail>`

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  heroes: Hero[];
  selectedHero: Hero;

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }

  getHeroes(): void {
  this.heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  this.getHeroes();
  }

  onSelect(hero: Hero): void {
    this.selectedHero = hero;
  }
}
```

How do I make the first hero item selected when it first starts
and i want to change selectedHero when i click another hero item

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
this.heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => {
  this.heroes = heroes;
  this.selectedHero = this.heroes[0];
});
```